# CheckBoxList control losing all items after post back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, list, checkbox, webforms

I have a `CheckBoxList` on page. All controls on page are in `UpdatePanel`.

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="AreaCheckBoxList" Width="300px" runat="server" onchange="RemoveItems()" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
  <asp:ListItem Value="" style="display: none"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Add item to it when click on a anchor tag with javascript.

```
 <a class="button" onclick="addToCheckBoxListControl()" />

 function addToCheckBoxListControl() {

        var tableRef = document.getElementById('<%= AreaCheckBoxList.ClientID %>');
        var list = document.getElementById('<%= AreaDropDownList.ClientID  %>');
        var valueValue = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
        var textvalue = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
        if (!isValueAlreadyExist(tableRef, valueValue)) {
            var rowArray = tableRef.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var rowCount = rowArray.length;
            var rowElement = tableRef.insertRow(rowCount);
            var columnElement = rowElement.insertCell(0);

            var checkBoxRef = document.createElement('input');

            var labelRef = document.createElement('label');

            checkBoxRef.type = 'checkbox';
            checkBoxRef.value = valueValue;
            labelRef.innerHTML = textvalue;

            columnElement.appendChild(checkBoxRef);
            columnElement.appendChild(labelRef);
        }
    }
```

I have a button on page, `CheckBoxList` control losing all items(items add with javascript) after button click.

```
AreaCheckBoxList.Items.Count -----> =1
```

Comment: Have you done any research on this yet?

Comment: also show your javascript code!

Comment: onchange="RemoveItems()" not doing anything?

Comment: @ChrisBuckler : Remove item when checked item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are binding the data to `CheckBoxList` from the code behind and you are checking the `IsPostBack` before data binding. so your data is only available for the direct page loads and not available for the postbacks.

***EDIT***

---

Seems your problem is JavaScript code is not executing after the postback. You can register the JavaScript function when updatepanel complete the request.Try this code to call your JavaScript function after updatepanel complete request.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(addToCheckBoxListControl)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523(v=vs.100).aspx

> The pageLoaded event is raised after all content on the page is
>   refreshed, whether it was refreshed because of a synchronous
>   (full-page) postback or an asynchronous postback. You can use this
>   event to provide a custom transition effect for updated content.

***UPDATE2***

---

You asked only part of the question. It seems the real problem is, you are adding items to the `CheckBoxList` using JavaScript and want to access it in code behind. It is not possible. if you modified the `CheckBoxList` in JavaScript, it would not persist server-side and would disappear after PostBack occurred.

So my advice for this situation is, replace your `<a>` tag with asp.net link button and it will do a postback when you click. on that click event you can add the element on serverside. so it will available both serverside and client side for you.

Comment: Thanks, No i add items to checkboxlist with javascript .

Comment: @ar.gorgin: See the updated answer. it will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but i add item in Checkboxlist when click on anchor tag `<a class="button" onclick="addToCheckBoxListControl()" />`